# OBIEE 12C _ analytics_ login using different user other than weblogic

Tags: weblogic12c, obiee

How to login into Oracle analytics (OBIEE12c) without using weblogic user or using any other user added in LDAP?

If I am trying to login into analytics using any other user added in LDAP
it is showing error as "This specified credentials could not be authenticated"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

a) You're trying to log on to Oracle Analytics. Not "Weblogic" Analytics. Weblogic is just the backend infrstructure for Oracle Analytics.

b) If your users are in an LDAP, then that LDAP must be an authentication provider inside of the Weblogic infrastructure.